# how to set handler to show imageview in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-handler

I want to show some views after a delay after clicking the button
but it doesn't work
I can't find the problem
or maybe this code not working

I set the image to invisible and want to show it after 26s of clicking the button
can anybody help me?

this is a full code of activity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_enter);


    ImageView yourImage = findViewById(R.id.allRightRegistered);

    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            yourImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }, 26000);

    VideoView videoview = findViewById(R.id.videoView);
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://"+getPackageName()+"/"+R.raw.intromovie);
    videoview.setVideoURI(uri);
    videoview.start();
}





@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    if (hasFocus) {
        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
    }
}

}
```

and its my xml code

```
<VideoView
    android:id="@+id/videoView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/Enter_Btn"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="90dp"
    android:text="Im Ready To Enter\nCoffee Melody"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.499" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/allRightRegistered"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/all_right_registered" />
```

I using motion layout by the way
it has 3 constraints

[image: this is shot of my design]

this is my design
in the first constraint, I set the button to invisible
in the second one, it will be visible
and after click the button it goes to the third one and the video will be play and button will be invisible
and I want one image and two buttons to be displayed after some time of clicking the button

Answer (score 1):

To run a long-delayed job, use a `Timer` instead of `Handler`:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button button;
    private ImageView imageView1;
    private Button button1;
    private Button button2;

    private TimerTask timerTask;
    private Timer timer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button = findViewById(R.id.button);
        imageView1 = findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        button1 = findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button2 = findViewById(R.id.button2);

        imageView1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        button1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        button2.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        timerTask = new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        imageView1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        button1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        button2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                });
            }
        };

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (timer != null) {
                    timer.cancel();
                }
                timer = new Timer();
                timer.schedule(timerTask, 26000);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        timer.cancel();
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks,it worked without the set the button for it. but  when i set the onclicklistener it didnt work.

Comment: You're welcome :) I don't understand what do you want to do with button. Would you please explain it?

Comment: i want to after clicking the button of user,timer get start and after 26s,one image view and 2 other button will show for user,like animation...

Comment: I have changed the answer to fit your described situation. Please check it out, hoping the problem gets solved.

Comment: nop...that didnt worked either...are you from iran?cuase i like to ask some questions from someone has more expierence from me